# finding the pdf for $y$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ that is $X$ is a random variable with normal distribution with mean$=0$ and standard deviation$=1$ and $$f_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$ Let $y=g(X)=\dfrac{1}{x}$. Now find the pdf for $Y$.

The first thing is that $y\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ and that $y'=-1x^{-2}<0$ which means that $y$ is a decreasing function. Next $g^{-1}(y)=\dfrac{1}{y}\implies \dfrac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)=-1y^{-2}=\dfrac{-1}{y^2}$ But now if $x\in(0,\infty)$ then $y\in(0,\infty)$. It follows that $$f_y(y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\dfrac{-1}{2y^2}}\left|\frac{-1}{y^2}\right|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\dfrac{-1}{2y^2}}*\frac{1}{y^2}$$ Similarly if $x\in(-\infty,0)$ then $y\in(-\infty,0)$. You get the same thing as above. Thus it follows that $$f_y(y)= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\dfrac{-1}{2y^2}}\left|\frac{-1}{y^2}\right|=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\dfrac{-1}{2y^2}}*\frac{1}{y^2}$$ for $y\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes, this seems correct to me. I am not sure if it is necessary to take two cases (x<0) and (x>0), but the result is fine.

Comment: I just did two cases since 0 was not in the domain/codomain of the pdf of x.

Comment: It's not incorrect; it's just unnecessary in this case because the derivative is an even function.  It is good practice to check though, for times when that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\checkmark$ Yes, that looks long winded but correct.

The support for $Y$ must be $(-\infty, 0)\cup(0,\infty)$.   Or equivalently: $(-\infty,\infty)\setminus\{0\}$

The transformation is:

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y)
 & = f_X\circ g^{-1}(y)\cdot \bigg|\frac{\mathrm d g^{-1}(y)}{\mathrm d y}\bigg|
 & : f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\operatorname {\bf 1}_{(-\infty,\infty)}(x)\,,\,  g(x) = x^{-1}
\\[2ex]
& = \frac{e^{-1/2y^2} }{ y^2\sqrt{2\pi}} \operatorname {\bf 1}_{(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)}(y)
& \because g^{-1}(y)=y^{-1}\,,\, (g^{-1})'(y) = -y^{-2}
\end{align}$$